# How to remove code block from Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, block

I am trying to remove a code section from my controller so that it looks clean and thin. In one of my controller I have to use many conditions and that is making my controller look very heavy. I just want to remove just that code block in other file and want to include it into my controller.
[My controller code](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/4cabf4d8dbd2012c7ee2c0b0675d619c)

Here you can see I am using some logic like:

```
   if search == 'Primary'
    if rain_fall_type == "Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing"

      if compare == "None"
        search = "None"
        rain_fall_type
      elsif compare == "All"
        rain_fall_type = compare
        data = [
          "Crops",
          "Livestock",
          "Forestry and Logging",
          "Fishing and Aquaculture",
        ]
      else
        search = "None"
        rain_fall_type = compare
      end

    elsif rain_fall_type == "None"
      rain_fall_type

      data = [
        "Primary",
      ]

    else
      data = [
        "Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing",
        "Mining and Quarrying",
      ]
    end
    ......
```

I want this section to be in some other files and want to call it as it is. I can write a function and a method and return values. My question is can I call this code block as it is without returning function or anything. For example I need to do something like this:

```
  a = if test == "a"
       #my code
    end

   #and in my controller 

  def test
     a 
  end
```

Can we do this in ruby put all code block in one file and call that value in my controller.

Comment: I don't know I just want to write this code block in some file and just want to call this code block.

Comment: you can move this code to respective model and retrieve result with just calling methods from controller.

Comment: One suggestion: Use `switch case` instead of multiple `elsif`.

Comment: I can't use this in model I want this code block in module or any other file

Comment: then go for module.

Comment: you can use helper methods as well. Also In helper method search params will be accessible.

Comment: What is a "may condition"?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo many condition

Comment: Two instances of `rain_fall_type` that appear in the body of the `if compare == "None"` and `elsif rain_fall_type == "None"` conditions are redundant. They are not doing anything meaningful.

Comment: Yes there few conditions which are not it use

Comment: I think you should create a module that handles this logic. In this [link](http://codefol.io/posts/Where-Do-I-Put-My-Code/) you can find more information. Also, I would suggest using a `switch case` instead of `if else` [exapmle](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/ruby-elsif-statements-vs-case-statements-which-is-better-for-production).

Answer (score 0):

To give you a short answer, so you can start right away you can do something like this:

```
if search == 'Primary'
  data, search = RainFallSearcher.call(rain_fall_type, compare)
end

class RainFallSearcher
  def call(rain_fall_type, compare)
    if rain_fall_type == "Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing"
      if compare == "None"
        search = "None"
        rain_fall_type
      elsif compare == "All"
        rain_fall_type = compare
        data = [
          "Crops",
          "Livestock",
          "Forestry and Logging",
          "Fishing and Aquaculture",
        ]
      else
        search = "None"
        rain_fall_type = compare
      end
    elsif rain_fall_type == "None"
      data = [
        "Primary",
      ]
    else
      data = [
        "Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing",
        "Mining and Quarrying",
      ]
    end

    return data, search
  end
end
```

You can then have `RainFallSearcher` in a location that's loaded by Rails (I would choose `app/services`.

You are not forced to have all your logic in the controllers or the models, it's actually recommended to have them quite thin, and create simple (or complex) Ruby objects to deal with the logic.

One of the "patterns" I like in Rails is "Service Object" (there are various discussion and naming convention), so google that and you can get more information.

This article is quite explanatory: https://www.engineyard.com/blog/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services